# SQL Server : populate table with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server. I have a bit of a challenging problem (at least for me!).

I have a table with information about TV Shows; the first column is the show's `Title`, the second is `Genre`, third is `Language`, the fourth column is the premiere date of the show, which has the format: `2017-11-03`.

What I would like to do is duplicate each row for a span of dates from this premiere date to 4 months in the future. So, if the current row reads
`2017-11-03`, I would like to copy this row for each date in this range, and then do the same thing for the next tv show (next row).

Can this be done in SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: It can, with cross apply and a calendar table. Some sample data and expected output is always nice, though. [Here is a good dimension table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) that can be used for the join, though you could do this with at `CTE` and a numbers / tally table as well

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that, I'll be sure to post sample data in the future!

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli The near future maybe? This site can help when to format tab-delimited text (e.g. by copying from Excel or most results grids) into text tables: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is with a CROSS APPLY in concert with an ad-hoc tally table

This will generate 4 months of data for each record in your source data.

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.D
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,A.Premier,DateAdd(Month,4,A.Premier))+1) 
                       D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.Premier) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1
              ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

-- truncated ---

[image]

**Googled it... I Love Lucy premiered October 15, 1951**  Should have done that first.

Comment: I am using this code to create a similar table. How could I add another column (lets day D2) with the nr of days passed for each day in column D: 0 for 1950-07-03; 1 for 1950-07-04, etc.? Thanks

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Having a little trouble with the visual.   Perhaps if you post a question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sure and thanks @JohnCappelletti. I've just posted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837665/create-calendar-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use a similar method inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101';
declare @years    int  = 4;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
```

---

Use either like so:

```
select d.date, t.*
from dates d
  inner join tv_shows t
    on d.date >= t.premiere_date
   and d.date <= dateadd(month,4,t.premiere_date)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XSRG45354

returns:

```
+------------+-------+---------+----------+---------------+
|    date    | title |  genre  | language | premiere_date |
+------------+-------+---------+----------+---------------+
| 2017-11-03 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2017-11-04 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2017-11-05 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2017-11-06 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
....                
| 2018-02-28 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2018-03-01 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2018-03-02 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
| 2018-03-03 | one   | example | english  | 2017-11-03    |
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is with a numbers table.  Here is one method of constructing one big enough:

```
with n as (
      select 0 as n union all
      select n.n from n where n.n < 50
     )
select tv.*, dateadd(week, n.n, tv.premierdate) as showdate
from tvshows tv join
     n
     on dateadd(week, n.n, tv.premierdate) <= dateadd(month, 4, tv.premierdate);
```

Comment: Hi. This was a great suggestion. Could you please explain why you wrote "n.n < 50" ?

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli . . . That is sufficient for four months (well, actually 18 would be sufficient, but who is counting?)